# Object Oriented Python with Flask Server?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask to expose some data-crunching code as a web service. 
I'd like to have some class variables that my Flask functions can access.

Let me walk you through where I'm stuck:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

class MyServer:
  def __init__(self):
    globalData = json.load(filename)

  @app.route('/getSomeData')
  def getSomeData():
    return random.choice(globalData) #select some random data to return

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I run `getSomeData()` outside of Flask, it works fine. But, when I run this with Flask, I get `500 internal server error`. There's no magic here, and Flask has no idea that it's supposed to initialize a `MyServer` object. How can I feed an instance of MyServer to the `app.run()` command?

I *could* admit defeat and put `globalData` into a database instead. But, is there an other way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create an instance of `MyServer` just outside the scope of your endpoints and access its attributes. This worked for me:

```
class MyServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.globalData = "hello"

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

my_server = MyServer()

@app.route("/getSomeData")
def getSomeData():
    return my_server.globalData

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: This is a decent alternative, but you still can't write end-to-end tests AND mock out dependencies (like network or filesystem IO) because your dependencies are not injected. You can do something hacky like `unittest.mock.patch`, but then you have to take care to construct your real server the same way you construct your test server (except for the mocks, of course).

This is basically the Singleton antipattern

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a late reply, but I came across this question while facing a similar issue. I found flask-classful really good.
You inherit your class from FlaskView and register the Flask app with your MyServer class

http://flask-classful.teracy.org/#

In this case, with flask-classful, your code would look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_classful import FlaskView, route

app = Flask(__name__)

class MyServer(FlaskView):
  def __init__(self):
    globalData = json.load(filename)

  @route('/getSomeData')
  def getSomeData():
    return random.choice(globalData) #select some random data to return


MyServer.register(app, base_route="/")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Please replace `flask-classful` with `flask_classful` (see https://github.com/teracyhq/flask-classful )

Answer (score 6):

The least-coupled solution is to apply the routes at runtime (instead of at load time):

```
def init_app(flask_app, database_interface, filesystem_interface):
    server = MyServer(database_interface, filesystem_interface)
    flask_app.route('get_data', methods=['GET'])(server.get_data)
```

This is very testable--just invoke `init_app()` in your test code with the mocked/faked dependencies (`database_interface` and `filesystem_interface`) and a flask app that has been configured for testing (`app.config["TESTING"]=True` or something like that) and you're all-set to write tests that cover your entire application (including the flask routing).

The only downside is this isn't very "Flasky" (or so I've been told); the Flask idiom is to use `@app.route()`, which is applied at load time and is necessarily tightly coupled because dependencies are hard-coded into the implementation instead of injected into some constructor or factory method (and thus complicated to test).

Comment: Flask passes in server.get_data the instance of MyServer, but where's the request data?

Answer (score 3):

The following code is a simple solution for OOP with Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request


class Server:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.app = Flask(name)

        @self.app.route('/')
        def __index():
            return self.index()

        @self.app.route('/hello')
        def __hello():
            return self.hello()

        @self.app.route('/user_agent')
        def __user_agent():
            return self.user_agent()

        @self.app.route('/factorial/<n>', methods=['GET'])
        def __factorial(n):
            return self.factorial(n)

    def index(self):
        return 'Index Page'

    def hello(self):
        return 'Hello, World'

    def user_agent(self):
        return request.headers.get('User-Agent')

    def factorial(self, n):
        n = int(n)
        fact = 1
        for num in range(2, n + 1):
            fact = fact * num
        return str(fact)

    def run(self, host, port):
        self.app.run(host=host, port=port)


def main():
    server = Server(__name__)
    server.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To test the code, browse the following urls:

- http://localhost:5000/
- http://localhost:5000/hello
- http://localhost:5000/user_agent
- http://localhost:5000/factorial/10

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` on the decorator.

Comment: Looks like [I'm not the only one](/questions/41276177/using-a-decorator-function-defined-as-an-instance-variable)

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but heres a quick implementation that i use to register routes at init time

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template
from functools import partial


registered_routes = {}
def register_route(route=None):
    #simple decorator for class based views
    def inner(fn):
        registered_routes[route] = fn
        return fn
    return inner

class MyServer(Flask):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not args:
            kwargs.setdefault('import_name',__name__)
        Flask.__init__(self,*args ,**kwargs)
        # register the routes from the decorator
        for route,fn in registered_routes.items():
            partial_fn = partial(fn,self)
            partial_fn.__name__ = fn.__name__
            self.route(route)(partial_fn)


    @register_route("/")
    def index(self):
        return render_template("my_template.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyServer(template_folder=os.path.dirname(__file__)).run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to approach MyServer class as a resource 
I believe that [flask_restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can help you:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import json
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class MyServer(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.globalData = json.load(filename)

    def get(self):
        return np.random.choice(self.globalData)

api.add_resource(MyServer, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```