# Port issue when using Flask app with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wamp, mod-wsgi

I have deployed a Flask app(REST API) on Apache server. The Apache server is part of the WAMP setup. Its a windows 10 machine. When I run the flask app using flask server, I can bind it to any port and it works. But when I try to use it from mod_wsgi, I get the error

> OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Apache is running on port no 5000. I was expecting flask app to use the same port and execute the python code. What am I doing wrong.

In the virtual host config is given below

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/AppDir/"
Alias /CourseReco/ "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/AppDir/"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/AppDir/">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes Includes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html index.py
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

The app_API.wsgi file is

```
#!d:/development/anaconda/envs/app_api/python.exe
import sys

import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\wamp64\www\AppDir")

from app_API import app as application
```

The app_API.py file looks like this. The answer from this question has been used to instantiate another class

[Object Oriented Python with Flask Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925217/object-oriented-python-with-flask-server)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from apilogic import apilogic
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
import os
class app_API:
    applogic= apilogic() #I want to load data once and not for every API call so doing this

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/getData")
def GetData():
    input=request.args.get('arg1')
    return app_API().applogic.send_data(input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779304/8916412

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am running the python script using mod_wsgi as an API so I cant let the UAC window open there. Secondly my python.exe path is present in windows firewall. Also the Apache is running on port 5000. so with mod_wsgi, flask should run on 5000 port be default isnt it?